# haproxy http-response replace

Tags: regex, pcre, haproxy, response-headers

I am trying to replace this part of the string in the response header "abc,def,ghi,jkl" . Please note this value is NOT static.

```
  My-Customer-Header: My-Test:abc,def,ghi,jkl:12345
```

Using this regex I am able to grab strings between the colon. i.e. "My-Test" & "12345" https://regex101.com/r/Ebkzjb/1

Here is what i am trying to replace value..

```
  My-Test:XYZ:12345
```

Here is my haproxy config line..

```
  http-response replace-value  My-Customer-Header (.*)((?<=:)(.*)(?=:))(.*) \1XYZ\2
```

Syntactically, haproxy config is loading but i may not have the regex properly. Can you please help with haproxy config for replace the value.

Comment: Shouldn't just selecting everything between the colons work? AKA, `:(.+):`

Comment: Yes it does..i think the issue was with haproxy config. Instead of "replace-value" i have used "replace-header" it's working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me

```
 http-response replace-header My-Customer-Header (.*)((?<=:)(.*)(?=:))(.*) \1XYZ\4
```